# Ranked-categorical variables in Artificial Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-data, continuous-data

As far as I understand, input variables in Artificial Neural Networks (ANN) must be continuous, right? (And there are a number of methods to convert categorical to continuous variables described in the literature.) However, I wonder if ranked-categorical variables (e.g., with classes 1, 2, and 3, where is 1 = low, 2 = average, 3 = high) should also be transformed into continuous variables before they can be included into an ANN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categorical features can be nominal (no ordering, like race, gender, religion, etc.), or ordinal (ranked, like in [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale)).

The method to feed in [nominal variable](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/nominal-variable/)s is by [one-hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f), which is straight-forward. So in the case you have a `Colour` feature consisting of `Red`, `Blue`, `Green`, you would just create 3-1 binary features to represent the feature. Here 3 is the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of your nominal feature. There are readily available pre-processing functions in many languages that do this for you, e.g. [in Python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

For ordinal variables, you could still feed in the feature using one-hot encoding. However, this would come at the expense of losing the ranking in between the feature values. For instance `movie review` as a feature can have the following values `rubbish`, `bad`, `mediocre`, `good`, `sensational`.  In this case, you are better of using [label-encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), where you map each category to, e.g. an integer, in a way that preserves the distances between feature values.

Finally, in answer to your question, the mapped values from label-encoding, which you would feed into neural networks or [GLM's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) in general, do not need to be (and indeed cannot be) continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Inputs to neural networks do not have to be continuous.** Other examples are binary or integer variables.

You can certainly use [ordinal variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data) too.

Comment: How? please provide some evidence or support.